# From Gmail to Facebook

Tags: facebook, email, automation, gmail

Is there any way to post messages received in an email, directly as a Facebook post?

If yes, how can I do that?
I want to automate a page in Fb to spend less time there

Comment: The question doesn't follow the guidelines of [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, one way of doing it would be to create a service or scheduled task which periodically does the following:

- Use [gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) to get all unread messages
- Each message will have an ID and you are able to check whether it has been read
- Use the IDs to [retrieve the message bodies](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get)
- Use Facebook API to post the body data to the page

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Ballerina](http://ballerinalang.org/) to create a stand-alone program or a service that you can invoke when it's needed. Use the [facebook connector](http://ballerinalang.org/docs/api/0.8/org.wso2.ballerina.connectors.facebook.html) to get a list of comments and posts **from your facebook page**, create a payload string and send it to a destination email using the [gmail connector](http://ballerinalang.org/docs/api/0.8/org.wso2.ballerina.connectors.gmail.html). Look at the samples shipped with the distribution to get a head start.